# Java App Consume POST request and Open New Browser Page Displaying content

Tags: java, angular

I'm looking for design advice. An external vendor is sending me data in an HTTP POST request which I will consume in my Java application. I need to consume that data and then display it in a new browser web page.

Currently, I consume the POST request, store the data in cache, then I have the vendor redirect the user to my Angular UI page which does a HTTP Get and retrieves the data just posted, then I clear the cache.

It works but I know this cannot be the best way to handle this. Any thoughts?

This is a simplified version of the code for my controller class

public class myController {

```
@Inject
IVendorObject obj;

@Inject
CacheManager cache;

@POST
@Path("/post-vendor-data")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createThisObject(@Valid VendorObject obj) {
    cache.put("myKey", obj);    
    return Response.ok(OBJ).build();
}

@GET
@Path("/get-vendor-data")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public VendorObject getThisObject() {
    obj = cache.get("myKey"); 
    cache.remove("myKey");
    return obj;
}
```

}

Comment: The vendor can redirect to the your UI page at beginning through POST request with all data that's caching now. I hope :)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I don't believe you can send a POST request directly to a UI page, unless it's a simple HTML form post.

Comment: It's possible, moreover it's widely used

Comment: If the data should be shown only on one page then all received data can be stored inside of returning html as json in `script` tag.
Otherwise I would save the data in user's http session.

Comment: Thanks, I'm exploring the first option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar requirement, this is a much better and probably the simplest option, thanks to the comments above from edwgiz for inspiring me to go in this direction.

Caching, redirection, and Angular have been eliminated and I just forward the request to a jsp page. Both methods above have now been reduced to:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/post-vendor-data")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void createThisObject(@Valid VendorObject obj) throws IOException, ServletException {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("myObject", obj);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```